# Different values when importing mysql data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Why do I get different values when importing data from server computer to my computer

source value = `Kirstinehøj 17`
became this `KirstinehÃ¸j 17`

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through my web application (Apache, MySQL, PHP, ...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through-my-web-application-apache-mysql-php)

Comment: encoding. that's the simplest thing i can say.

Comment: oh... sorry for being so stupid... i have no idea that's because encoding... thank you very much

Comment: Are you importing and/or exporting with phpMyAdmin? You tagged phpmyadmin but didn't specify whether you're using it for both ends of the transfer. You may also wish to look at http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data

Comment: yes i'm importing/exporting with phpmyadmin... thanks for your link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your default_charset in php.ini, then using header() from within your code, before any output:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```